# Bind jqxGrid using WCF service

Tags: c#, json, wcf, jqxgrid

Hello I'm trying to bind a jqxGrid but nothing works at the moment.
Some information to start: I've a data access project that uses Entity Framework to access database. The data access project methods are called by custom SharePoint 2013 WCF server. The WCF methods looks like

```
    public string GetData()
    {
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(BL.GetData());
    }
```

BL.GetData() returns an IList that I format in JSON in the WCF service.
If I navigate to the GetData method url I can see the JSON result so I suppose that this part works.

This my html page:

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="jqxbuttons.js"></script>
<script src="jqxcore.js"></script>
<script src="jqxdata.js"></script>
<script src="jqxdropdownlist.js"></script>
<script src="jqxgrid.columnsresize.js"></script>
<script src="jqxgrid.filter.js"></script>
<script src="jqxgrid.grouping.js"></script>
<script src="jqxgrid.js"></script>
<script src="jqxgrid.pager.js"></script>
<script src="jqxgrid.selection.js"></script>
<script src="jqxgrid.sort.js"></script>
<script src="jqxlistbox.js"></script>
<script src="jqxmenu.js"></script>
<script src="jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var source = {
            type: "GET",
            datatype: "json",
            datafields: [
                { name: 'Field1'},
                { name: 'Field2'},
            ],
            url: 'Service.svc/GetData',
            cache: false,
        };

        //Preparing the data for use    
        var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source, {
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            downloadComplete: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { return data.d; }
        });

        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
            source: dataAdapter,
            columns: [
                { text: 'Field1', dataField: 'Field1' },
                { text: 'Field2', dataField: 'Field2' }]
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="jqxgrid">
</div>
```

The JSON looks like this:

```
[{
    "Field1": "Field1",
    "Field1": "Field1"
},
{
    "Field2": "Field2",
    "Field2": "Field2"
}]
```

What is wrong?
Thank you

Comment: If you're using WCF, rather than returning a string, you need to return the list of objects themselves.  WCF will format them for you using the data contract serializer.  See [How do I return clean JSON from a WCF Service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086666/how-do-i-return-clean-json-from-a-wcf-service).

Comment: For entity framework, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791169/return-entity-framework-objects-from-wcf or maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558234/wcf-rest-service-json-and-using-my-model-data-with-entity-framework-database-f